# Strange "counts" matrix from matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, histogram2d

I would like to get the 2d numpy array from the 2dhist function. After obtaining the counts, I would like to plot the data in the pyplot.imshow() function to further add some information. The integers that are allowed to appear in my list are between 0 and 11 (therefore 12 bins).

However, I get a strange matrix.

```
data1 = [2, 3, 3, 10, 3, 2, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 2, 10, 10, 9, 2, 9, 10, 
9, 9, 9, 3, 10, 3, 2, 10, 1]
data2 = [5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 4, 4, 8, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 
4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 5]
n_bins = 12
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
counts, xedge, yedge, image = ax.hist2d(data1, data2, bins=n_bins)

result: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [2., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])

transposed:
 array([[0., 3., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

If we look at the data lists closely, we see that for example the integer 0 never appears. How can therefore be an entry in the first column?

I would very much appreciate your insides.
Thank you.

Comment: Your list have numbers starting from 1 and going up to 10. So 10 unique numbers. Why do you have 12 bins then? There is neither any 0, nor any 11 in either of your lists

Comment: If you print `xedge` and `yedge` you will see the actual bin edges which start from 1 and go up to 10 : `[ 1.    1.75  2.5   3.25  4.    4.75  5.5   6.25  7.    7.75  8.5   9.25
 10.  ]`. So the 0 which you see in the counts columns is not the number 0 but the number of values falling in the first bin 1 to 1.75

Comment: Thank you for your help! Even though my current array only contained numbers from 1 to 10, numbers from 0 to 11 would have been possible. The clue with the xedge and yedge helped a lot. I set now bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] to get the desired shape.